# Magento subscribe form not showing

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm working on a website and my page doesn't show the subscribe form...

I've added this to my newsletter.xml:

```
    <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
    <reference name="newsletter">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="news.subscribe" as="news.subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

and this to my news_home.phtml:

```
  <section id="news_and_fun_home" class="block small">
    <div class="block-top"></div>
    <div class="block">
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/105681634975039284210/posts" target="_blank"><div class="follow-google"></div></a>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('news.subscribe'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="block-bottom"></div>
</section>
```

i'm kinda new in magento... Can someone explain me what to do exactly?

Also this isnt working:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('newsletter/subscribe')->setTemplate('newsletter/subscribe.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes i did flush cache

Comment: can you please confirm,news.homeblock is working or not???

Comment: Post your update layout handle also

Comment: clear cache if  direct call of phtml  is not working

Comment: Did that, still not working... It's so weird

Answer (score 1):

First of all ,check the `news_home.phtml` file `reference name is newsletter` in xml file
if,you to show this block then then you should  call

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("news.subscribe"); ?>`  in
reference block `newsletter (<reference name="newsletter">)` 's phtml file

Comment: reference name "newsleter",just check it

Comment: change  news.subscribe to any other name

Comment: change alias name to as="news_subscribe" also change in news_home.phtml

Answer (score 0):

in newsletter.xml:

```
<default>
        <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </default>
```

in news_home.phtml:

```
<section id="news_and_fun_home" class="block small">
    <div class="block-top"></div>
    <div class="block">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sluban.nl" target="_blank"><div class="follow-facebook"></div></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/slubaneurope" target="_blank"><div class="follow-twitter"></div></a>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/105681634975039284210/posts" target="_blank"><div class="follow-google"></div></a>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock("newsletter/subscribe")
                    ->setTemplate("newsletter/subscribe.phtml")
                    ->toHtml();
        ?>
    </div>
```

And check in your magento/app/design/frontend/Your Theme/default/layout/local.xml

if found below line then comment it:

```
<remove name="left.newsletter"/>
```